# Filtering a list contained in a data frame with a vector. R studio

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame of two columns: one, called "path_name", contains 74 pathways and the other one, called "genes", contains a list of genes for each pathway.  Furthermore, I have a vector containing 28 mutated genes. I need to know in which pathway I can find each mutated gene. For example:

```
mutated_genes=("MAP4K4"  "TRAF2"  "CACNG3" ...)

hsa04010__117 MAP4K4,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*, DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,PPM1A,AKT3,AKT3,AKT3,ZAK,MAP3K12,MAP3K13,TRAF2,CASP3,IL1R1,IL1R1,TNFRSF1A,IL1A,IL1A,TNF,RAC1,RAC1,RAC1,RAC1,MAP2K7,MAPK8,MAPK8,MAPK8,MECOM,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,MAP4K3,MAPK8IP2 MAP4K1....

hsa04014__118 MAP4K4,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10* ...
```

I need something like this:

```
hsa04010= MAP4K4 TRAF2
hsa01014= CACNG3
....
```

I have no idea how to filter a list contained in a data frame using R. I have tried to do it using subset function but it's not correct. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me the exact structure of your data frame - str(my_df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update -** 
`dplyr` approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mutated = paste(mutated_genes[unlist(
    lapply(mutated_genes, function(x) x %in% strsplit(genes, ",")[[1]]))], collapse=","),
    path_name = gsub("_.*$", "", path_name)) %>%
  select(-genes) %>%
  data.frame()
```

**Output is:**

```
df1
  path_name      mutated
1  hsa04010 MAP4K4,TRAF2
2  hsa04014       MAP4K4
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <-structure(list(path_name = c("hsa04010__117", "hsa04014__118"
), genes = c("MAP4K4,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,DUSP3*,PPM1A,AKT3,AKT3,AKT3,ZAK,MAP3K12,MAP3K13,TRAF2,CASP3,IL1R1,IL1R1,TNFRSF1A,IL1A,IL1A,TNF,RAC1,RAC1,RAC1,RAC1,MAP2K7,MAPK8,MAPK8,MAPK8,MECOM,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,HSPA1A,MAP4K3,MAPK8IP2,MAP4K1", 
"MAP4K4,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*,DUSP10*")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

mutated_genes <- c("MAP4K4", "TRAF2", "CACNG3")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Prem.

Comment: Hello Prem, the function doesn't match for unique value. If I have MAP4K and MAP4K1, it matches for both. I still have the same problem with this function [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185468/column-with-specific-value-r)