# Column with specific value R

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have a data frame of 3 columns (genes, varian_type and samples) and another one of two columns (pathways and genes). In the second one I have a list of genes in each pathway. So now I would like to create a new data frame of 4 columns (genes, variant_type, samples and pathways) that shows the pathway or pathways in which each gene is present. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

1)

```
     Hugo_Symbol    Variant_Type         Tumor_Sample_Barcode
1       ZAP70          SNP           TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09
```

2)

```
structure(list(circuit_names = c("hsa04014__44", "hsa04014__33", 
"hsa04014__37", "hsa04014__24", "hsa04014__26", "hsa04014__30"
), mutated = c("ZAP70,NF1,MAPK1,RAF1,CSF1R,RASGRP1,MAP2K1,MAP2K1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,NF1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCG1", 
"ZAP70,NF1,AKT3,CSF1R,BAD,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,PIK3R5,NF1,BCL2L1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCG1,AKT3", 
"ZAP70,NF1,AKT3,CSF1R,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,PIK3R5,NF1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCG1,FOXO4,AKT3", 
"ZAP70,NF1,CSF1R,RGL2,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,NF1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCG1", 
"ZAP70,NF1,CSF1R,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,NF1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCE1", 
"ZAP70,NF1,CSF1R,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,NF1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCG1,PLCE1"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

3) I wont something like this

```
    structure(list(Hugo_Symbol = c("ZAP70", "TTN", "TTN", "PRKCD", 
"PIK3CA", "TLR3"), Variant_Type = c("SNP", "SNP", "SNP", "SNP", 
"SNP", "SNP"), Tumor_Sample_Barcode = c("TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09", 
"TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09", "TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09", 
"TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09", "TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09", 
"TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09"), Pathways = c("hsa04014__44, hsa04014__33, hsa04014__37, hsa04014__24", 
"hsa04530__11 20 16", "hsa04530__11 20 16", "hsa04722__37, hsa04722__35, hsa04722__33", 
"hsa04151__25, hsa04151__37, hsa04151__73", "hsa04620__23")), row.names = c("6", 
"8", "9", "11", "13", "16"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your data format is not much clear. Did you have imported them in R? If so, just use `dput` to share the relevant parts.

Comment: add `dput()` output.

Comment: sorry but where?

Comment: You can `dput(head(df))` and paste the output here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update -** Changed solution approach so that it also handles the case pointed out by OP. i.e. if `Hugo_Symbol` is `NF1` then logic should not matches `NF11` or `NF12`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1  %>%
  mutate(Hugo_Symbol = as.character(Hugo_Symbol)) %>%   #convert factor to character variable
  left_join(df2 %>%
              separate_rows(mutated, sep = ','), 
            by = c("Hugo_Symbol" = "mutated")) %>%
  group_by(Hugo_Symbol, Variant_Type, Tumor_Sample_Barcode) %>%
  summarise(Pathways = paste(unique(circuit_names), collapse = ","))   #combine distinct values in Pathways
```

which gives

```
  Hugo_Symbol Variant_Type Tumor_Sample_Barcode         Pathways                                     
1 NF1         SNP          TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09 hsa04014__44,hsa04014__33
```

**Sample data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Hugo_Symbol = "NF1", Variant_Type = "SNP", Tumor_Sample_Barcode = "TCGA-E9-A1RC-01A-11D-A159-09"), .Names = c("Hugo_Symbol", 
"Variant_Type", "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

df2 <- structure(list(circuit_names = c("hsa04014__44", "hsa04014__33", 
"hsa04014__37", "hsa04014__24"), mutated = c("ZAP70,NF1,MAPK1,RAF1,CSF1R,RASGRP1,MAP2K1", 
"ZAP70,NF1,AKT3,CSF1R,BAD,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1", 
"ZAP70,NF11,AKT3,CSF1R,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF", 
"ZAP70,NF12,CSF1R,RGL2,RASGRP1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1,RASGRF1"
)), .Names = c("circuit_names", "mutated"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Prem. You have really helped me!

Comment: Hi Prem, I have realized that I have a problem with your function. The problem is that if I have, for example, MAP3K1 (Hugo_Symbol), the function matches for MAP3K11 or MAP3K14 or AMAP3K11 so the new column won't be correct. Can you help me?

Comment: Hello Prem, thank you but there is something wrong. This is the warning message: Column `Hugo_Symbol`/`mutated` joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector

Comment: Yes but there is another problem...Now in "Pathways" there are duplicated or tripled pathways.